What was the surprise that GLaDOS was going to do before the morality core dropped?
In the end of Portal 1 GLaDOS was going to surprise you, then the morality core dropped. That was not the surprise, but what was?

I think we can assume it was neurotoxin. Or confetti. Or neurotoxin laced with confetti.

Definitely not a cake...

@fez - A cake laced with neurotoxin, perhaps?

@Valorum - in my head - "but Nuerotoxin!!" X1000000 - Morality core "that's it, I'm outta here"
